# Orthogonality of irreducible and non-isomorphic representations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, young-tableaux

Let V and W be any two subspaces of $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ such that there exists two irreducible and non-isomorphic representations $\rho_V: G \to GL(V)$ and $\rho_W: G \to GL(W)$. Does this imply: V and W are orthogonal subspaces?

I am new to representation theory, so apologies if this is basic knowledge. I could not find a good proof/counterexample for this fact, but something along the lines is used in Proposition 1 in [Stembridge - Orthogonal sets of Young symmetrizers](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2009.08.004).
In this link, it is shown that Young symmetrizers corresponding to two different shapes are orthogonal by using the fact that they project onto irreducible and non-isomorphic representations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't sure what the question meant; to make sense of it, $V$ and $W$ would have had to be subspaces of a common space with some sort of form with respect to which we could measure orthogonality, and two abstract representations need not be presented in this way.

Your reference to [Stembridge - Orthogonal sets of Young symmetrizers](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aam.2009.08.004) suggested that you were thinking of, say, complex representations of a finite group $G$.  In this setting, the group algebra $\mathbb C[G]$ has a $V$-isotypic subspace (consisting of the matrix coefficients $g \mapsto \langle v^*, g\cdot v\rangle$ for $v \in V$ and $v^* \in V^*$) and a $W$-isotypic subspace (analogously defined).  These are orthogonal for the usual ($G$-equivariant) inner product on $\mathbb C[G]$, by the [Schur orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations).

EDIT: You have updated the question to indicate that you just want $V$ and $W$ to be two subspaces of $(\mathbb C^d)^{\otimes n}$, presumably with the usual inner product inherited from its natural identification with $\mathbb C^{d n}$.  (I'm not sure what the purpose of the separate $d$ and the $n$ parameters is.)  In this generality, the answer can be ‘no’ in all but the most trivial cases: consider, for example, the cyclic group of order $2$ acting trivially on a line $V$ in $(\mathbb C^2)^{\otimes1}$, and non-trivially on a non-orthogonal line $W$ in $(\mathbb C^2)^{\otimes1}$.  (This can even be extended, as you probably meant, to an action of the cyclic group on $(\mathbb C^2)^{\otimes1}$ that makes its actions on $V$ and $W$ subrepresentations.)

If you added, as you probably meant to do, the requirement that $G$ actually act on $(\mathbb C^d)^{\otimes n}$, preserving some inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ there (not necessarily the standard one!), and that the representations of $G$ on $V$ and $W$ make them subrepresentations of this big $d n$-dimensional representation (as is the case for finite groups $G$, again, by the [Schur orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations), when we embed abstract representations $G$-equivariantly in $\mathbb C[G] \cong (\mathbb C^{\lvert G\rvert})^{\otimes 1}$, equipped with its standard ‘$L^2$’ inner product), *then* the answer is once again ‘yes’, that the spaces of $V$ and $W$ are orthogonal *with respect to this $G$-fixed inner product*.  (I emphasise the need for consistency in the choice of inner product because *every* action of a finite group on a complex vector space preserves *some* inner product there.  For example, if we chose the lines in the example of the previous paragraph to be $V = \operatorname{Span}(1, 1)$ and $W = \operatorname{Span}(1, 0)$, then the inner product with squared norm $(x, y) \mapsto 2\lvert x\rvert^2 - 4\operatorname{Re}(x\overline y) + 5\lvert y\rvert^2$ is preserved by the cyclic group of order $2$, and, indeed, $V$ and $W$ are orthogonal with respect to this inner product even though they are not with respect to the ‘standard’ pairing.)

I will now prove the modified statement.  For every $v \in V$, the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) produces a unique element $T(v) \in W$ such that $\langle T(v), w\rangle$ equals $\langle v, w\rangle$ for all $w \in W$.  We have that $T : V \to W$ is $G$-equivariant (because $G$ preserves the inner product), so, since $V$ and $W$ are irreducible and non-isomorphic, $T$ must be identically $0$.  Then $\langle v, w\rangle = \langle T(v), w\rangle$ equals $0$ for all $v \in V$ and $w \in W$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. My question is motivated by the action of symmetric group $S_n$ on $(\mathbb{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$ (where it permutes the n vectors). Since, this group action preserves all inner products, I think from your proof, V and W will be orthogonal under all inner products.

Also, can you further explain:  the inner product with squared norm $(,) \to 2x^2 − 4 + 5^2$ is preserved by the cyclic group of order 2?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1161637), the action of $S_n$ on $(\mathbb C^d)^{\otimes n}$ preserves the *standard* inner product, but not *all* inner products. (There is a “$B$-indexed family of inner products”, where $B$ is the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices, in a slightly wrong sense that I won't specify here.) Every inner product can be converted to a $G$-fixed one by summing over its $G$-orbit. If you do that to the standard inner product, then you get the product that I wrote (suitably corrected—I forgot to Hermitian-ize).

Comment: Thanks! This makes a lot more sense now. Another dumb question: how does "
  preserves the inner product" imply "$T_{w_0}$ is G-equivariant"?  To prove that $T_{w_0}$ is  G-equivariant, I need to show $\rho_W(g) T_{w_0}(v) = T_{w_0}(\rho_V(g) v)$. How do I relate this to inner products?

Comment: In my previous attempts to prove this orthogonality on simple examples, I was often restricted by my inability to G-equivariance to inner products. So pointers here will be very useful :)

Comment: @LSpice OP didn't assume that the rep on $V$ and $W$ is induced by that on $(\mathbf{C}^d)^{\otimes n}$.

Comment: @YCor, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449517/orthogonality-of-irreducible-and-non-isomorphic-representations/449519#comment1161643_449519), right, that's the subject of my third paragraph.  But it seemed very likely to be what was meant, so I said so in the fourth paragraph, and thought I might as well answer that question, too.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out: $ \langle T(g.v), w \rangle = \langle g.v, w \rangle = \langle v, g^{-1} w \rangle = \langle T(v), g^{-1} w \rangle =  \langle g T(v), w \rangle$ for all w. This means T(g.v) = g T(v) in the subspace W. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @listener, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1161640), first, the $w_0$ there is irrelevant, oops (I originally had a slightly different argument in mind); you can ignore it.  The relevance is that $T$ is defined *via* the $G$-fixed inner product, so, suppressing quantifiers, we have $\langle g^{-1} T(g v), w\rangle = \langle T(g v), g w\rangle = \langle g v, g w\rangle = \langle v, w\rangle = \langle T(v), w\rangle$ (using the definition and $G$-fixedness alternately), so we can conclude from uniqueness that $g^{-1} T(g v)$ equals $T(v)$, and hence that $T(g v)$ equals $g T(v)$.

Comment: ([As](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449517/orthogonality-of-irreducible-and-non-isomorphic-representations/449519#comment1161647_449519) you [commented](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449517/orthogonality-of-irreducible-and-non-isomorphic-representations/449519#comment1161645_449519) even before I finished my response!)

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449517/orthogonality-of-irreducible-and-non-isomorphic-representations/449519#comment1161641_449519), a general point of view on this is the [uniqueness of maximal compact subgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_compact_subgroup#Existence_and_uniqueness). But here the idea is quite down to earth: given a (possibly non-$G$-fixed) inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$, define a new inner product by $\langle x, y\rangle' = \sum_{g \in G} \langle g x, g y\rangle$, suitably quantified, with sum replaced by Haar integral in the $G$-compact case.

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense.